# Pyramid + pserve occasional delay in response

Tags: pyramid, pylons

I'm running a pyramid web server. 99% of the time it works great. However randomly, as I try to reach an URL, the request just waits a random amount of time, a few seconds to a few dozens of seconds, with no message in the logs.

It can happen on any page, I didn't notice a pattern.

Nothing appears in the log, however if I kill the server, the browser notices it immediately ("This site can’t be reached"), and I get this in the pserve console :

```
^C----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 56409)
Traceback (most recent call last):
^C caught in monitor process
```

So it seems the server is handling the request, but before entering any method of mine..

The server runs with `../env/bin/pserve development.ini --reload`

I can't understand why / where it can be stuck. Any idea ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: This type of speculative question just isn't very easy to answer in a SO format. You need to break down your pipeline and measure timing at various points and see if you can come up with a better idea where the delays are occurring.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Indeed the question is quite obscure. I was wondering if there exists a common cause for this kind of delay. I'll try to activate more logs or traces on pyramid's side, and update the question if I get something.